# If it safe to return an InputStream from try-with-resource

Tags: java, return, inputstream, try-with-resources

Is it **safe** to return an input stream from a try-with-resource statement to handle the closing of the stream once the caller has consumed it?

```
public static InputStream example() throws IOException {
    ...
    try (InputStream is = ...) {
        return is;
    }
}
```

Comment: as soon as you get out of the function execution the resource goes out of scope and hence garbage collected... All in All.. Safe but useless....

Comment: @CoderNeji Apart from the part that you usually cannot tell when an unreferenced object will be garbage collected, the `InputStream`  is **closed**, not garbage collected (because there is still the 'live' reference returned from the method). What is out of scope is the `is` variable, but that is a different issue that is solved at compilation time.

Comment: thanks for explaination

Answer (score 6):

It's safe, but it will be closed, so I don't think it is particularly useful... (You can't reopen a closed stream.)

See this example:

```
public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(example());
}

public static InputStream example() throws IOException {
    try (InputStream is = Files.newInputStream(Paths.get("test.txt"))) {
        System.out.println(is);
        return is;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream@1db9742
sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream@1db9742
```

The (same) input stream is returned (same by reference), but it will be closed. By modifying the example to this:

```
public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
    InputStream is = example();
    System.out.println(is + " " + is.available());
}

public static InputStream example() throws IOException {
    try (InputStream is = Files.newInputStream(Paths.get("test.txt"))) {
        System.out.println(is + " " + is.available());
        return is;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream@1db9742 1000000
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.ensureOpen(FileChannelImpl.java:109)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.size(FileChannelImpl.java:299)
    at sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream.available(ChannelInputStream.java:116)
    at sandbox.app.Main.main(Main.java:13)
```